# jquery ui tabs Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm receiving this error: uncaught typeerror: object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' and haven't found any good links that have helped. Here is my markup can anybody please help me figure out why I'm having this problem?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
```

And the markup is:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-4"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
<div id="tabs-4"></div>
```

Comment: Is the closing ul and div just in this post or is that your markup?

Comment: Also the script tag opening is missing

Comment: Thanks I've got both of those listed, I mis-typed that info

Comment: Please read the documention, the html you've just added to your question is incorrect. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @HTn00b90 how can you mistype, use the original code please. If I see your markup correctly, and hope it's not a mistype too, then the `<div id="tabs">` is being closed to soon after the closing `</ul>`. It should enclose after `<div id="tabs-4"></div>`, second `<div id="tabs-1"></div>` is missing ..

Comment: Thanks friends, I've followed the documentation to a tee, even reverted to jquery ui version 1.10.2 and am still receiving the error.

Comment: @dbf yes, your proposed markup is what I have, my apologies for the confusion, i initially used a wonky text editor and was having to manually type the information instead of copying/pasting. I reverted back to the current jquery ui version because I was receiving 2 errors upon going back to 1.10.2

Comment: You still have errors in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

You are missing the `#` in front which indicates the element with `id="tabs"`

The setup for the tabs is like the following.  You seem to be missing all the tab contents and make sure that the jquery ui library is actually being loaded (path is correct):

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to include the #, twas a typo. Still receiving the error.

Comment: I updated the answer.  You seem to be missing all of the tab content areas. I've presented what the jquery UI page shows as the format for content.

Comment: I forgot to include that also just edited the question, thanks for the response however I'm still receiving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely calling another jquery library in the rest of the page below,
which is an older version, that does not contain tabs function. you need to remove that line
something like

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This happens usually with jsCarousel

If the problem still exists can you please post the link

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using an old version of Jquery. Try it again with the latest version. I had the same problem but when I used the 1.9.1 version of Jquery it worked.